# Адаптивная верстка, разрешения браузеров

Tags: html, css

При использовании инструментов разработчика в Goole Chrome для адаптивной верстки, а в частности режим адаптивного дизайна (для примера выберем разрешение iPhoneX) ширину и высоту окна выдает в 375 на 812 (как я понимаю в пикселях), что не совсем мне понятно, т.к. разрешение iPhoneX 1125x2436 и картинка соответсвует 375 на 812 - видно что применяются стили для минимального в медиазапросах разрешения. При измерении пиксельной линейкой некоторых размеров сайта, когда растягиваю окно браузера или сжимаю, они не соответствуют тому что ждешь (по пиксельной линейке сайт в 1700px сворачивается, а должен в 1400).

Comment: Потому что ретина. Один браузерный пиксель в айфоне соответствует трём реальным пикселям, так что хром всё правильно выдаёт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть разрешение телефонов, а есть физические пиксили. Вот статья https://habr.com/ru/post/229359/

Браузер показывает правильно, верь ему

Answer (score 1):

Расширяя предыдущий ответ на вопрос рекомендую к прочтению:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Сам в своё время когда только начинал пол дня потратил пока догадался.